# Express: want to do a big task after returning a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I have created a program to extract 7GB zip file. It works normally when it is moved by itself.

**Task 1.** When Express.js receives the request, it will immediately return the response.

**Task 2.** After returning the response, download the zip file from s3 according to the request.Then unzip it.Upload it to s3 when that is over.

**Task 3.** If you received multiple requests simultaneously, I would like to work on **Task 2** in order. Because processing it at the same time uses a lot of memory.

This code corresponds to **Task 2**. It works normally when it is moved by itself.

```
    const unzipUpload = path => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let rStream = s3.getObject({Bucket: 'bucket', Key: path})
                .createReadStream()
                    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
                    .on('entry', function (entry) {
                        if(entry.path.match(/__MACOSX/) == null){

                            // pause
                            if(currentFileCount - uploadedFileCount > 10) rStream.pause()

                            currentFileCount += 1
                            var fileName = entry.path;
                            let up = entry.pipe(uploadFromStream(s3,fileName))

                            up.on('uploaded', e => {
                                uploadedFileCount += 1
                                console.log(currentFileCount, uploadedFileCount)

                                //resume
                                if(currentFileCount - uploadedFileCount <= 10) rStream.resume()

                                if(uploadedFileCount === allFileCount) resolve()
                                entry.autodrain()
                            }).on('error', e => {
                                reject()
                            })
                        }

                    }).on('error', e => {
                        console.log("unzip error")
                        reject()
                    }).on('finish', e => {
                        allFileCount = currentFileCount
                    })
            rStream.on('error', e=> {
                console.log(e)
                reject(e)
            })
        })
    }

    function uploadFromStream(s3,fileName) {
        var pass = new stream.PassThrough();

        var params = {Bucket: "bucket", Key: "hoge/unzip/" + fileName, Body: pass};
        let request = s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
            if(err) pass.emit('error')
            if(!err) pass.emit('uploaded')
        })
        request.on('httpUploadProgress', progress => {
            console.log(progress)
        })

        return pass
    }
```

Here is the code I wrote to accomplish this task.

However, when receiving a request at the same time, processing starts at the same time and memory is consumed in large quantities.

```
router.post('/unzip', (req, res) => {
    let path = req.body.path
    res.json({message: 'OK.'})

    res.on('finish', () => {
        unzipUpload(path).then(() => {
            console.log("success")
        })
    })
})
```

Is there a way to minimize memory and realize this?

Comment: The most scalable way to do this would be to create a work queue and then one or more sub-processes that process queued items.  This will allow your Express process to stay free to serve web requests and the sub-process can do your S3 and unzip work.  You can design the queue processing to only process one item at a time if you need to.

Comment: http://queues.io/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your scenario I would suggest you to use queuing mechanism, RabbitMQ.

How will it help you:

**Task 1**: Will be done by your express, but before returning the response, you will publish a json message to the RMQ queue. This message will contain your Task 2&3 related required information.

Now your task 2 & 3 will be done by RMQ worker. Now as soon you publish your message and if a RMQ worker is free, it will pick up the message and start processing Task 2 & 3. Now if you get multiple requests to your node, you will just keep publishing message to RMQ.

The advantage here you will get is that your requests context/message will never be lost, RMQ will queue your messages. And if you want to achieve speed, you can spawn multiple workers.

Comment: This solution isn't limited to RabbitMQ. [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) is probably the most common node.js solution which is backed by redis, but any third party database/broker will do. [SQS](http://queues.io/#amazon_simple_queue_service) would be an option as they are already using S3